# How to retrieve each value from List<Object>

Tags: java, arrays, list, spring-mvc, object

When I execute this query I store the result into list object

```
Query vodquery = session.createQuery(
    "select vod.videoid,vod.videotitle,alb.language,alb.genre "+
    "from Videos as vod,Album as alb "+
    "where vod.videoType =:videotype and vod.albumId=alb.id "+
    "group by vod.videoId").setParameter("videotype","MOV");
List<Object> videolist = vodquery.list();
```

I need to retrieve each result, but when I use this code

```
for(int i = 0; i < videolist.size(); i++) {
    System.out.println(videolist.get(i));
}
```

result is

```
[Ljava.lang.Object;@b7e548
[Ljava.lang.Object;@12e0986
[Ljava.lang.Object;@1735396
```

When I use this code

```
for (int i=0; i<videolist.size(); i++){
   Object[] row = (Object[]) videolist.get(i);
   System.out.println("Element "+i+Arrays.toString(row));
}
```

Got the result like this

```
Element 0[VOD1000, sdf, English, Action, null, d, Entertainment, Action, comody, 0, null, null, dddddd]

Element 1[VOD1002, sdf, NONE, NONE]
Element 2[VOD1004, sdf, NONE, NONE]
Element 3[VOD1005, sdf, NONE, NONE]
```

But I need to fetch each value from each row. How can I do this. I need to go through each value from the result

Comment: Solutions below are right, but don't forget that if you need to do changes to the `List` object you will need to use an `Iterator` and its methods ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Change your loop :**

```
for (int i=0; i < videolist.size(); i++){
       Object[] row = (Object[]) videolist.get(i);
       for(Object obj : row) {
            System.out.println("Element "+ i +obj));  
       } 
    }
```

Comment: It shows the error The method toString(long[]) in the type Arrays is not applicable for the arguments (Object)

Answer (score 1):

You can use two nested loops:

```
for (Object[] row : videolist){
    for(Object value : row) {
        // use value here
    }
}
```

Comment: It is not object[]...It shows the erro Type mismatch: cannot convert from element type Object to Object[]

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this:

```
for (int i=0; i<videolist.size(); i++){
   Object[] row = (Object[]) videolist.get(i);
    for(Object value : row) {
        // use value here
    }
}
```